# Сохранение CSS-свойств у динамически добавленных блоков

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть блоки:

```
<div class="order-string-list">Текст 1</div>
<div class="order-string-list">Текст 2</div>
<div class="order-string-list">Текст 3</div>
```

Они загружаются асинхронно и могут добавляться или удаляться со страницы.

Есть кнопка:

```
<div class="open-new">Кнопка</div>
```

Которая меняет видимость данных блоков с помощью функции:

```
$("body").on("click", ".open-new", function(e) {
    $(".order-string-list").toggle();   
});
```

Но почему новые элементы не появляются с этим свойством? И как сделать так, чтобы свойства CSS распространялись также на новые объекты, то есть фактически происходило изменение в классе CSS, а не только в выбранных блоках с классом CSS?

Даже если поменять свойство, к примеру:

```
$(".order-string-list").css('background-color', 'red');
```

То существующие блоки окрасятся в красный, но новые не будут наследовать это свойство. Почему?

Comment: действительно любопытно... Обычно CSS к динамично созданным блокам применяется без проблем... А можно посмотреть код, который создает эти новые блоки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $(".order-string-list").css('background-color','red');

Проблема в том, что используя метод `css`, вы прописываете стиль прямо в `элемент` ( если коллекция, то в каждый `элемент коллекции` ) это называется `inline стиль` и он распространяется только на `элемент` где прописан и его потомков. В вашем случае, можно сделать так

**HTML**

```
<div class='parent'>
   <!-- тут ваши дивы -->
   <div class="order-string-list"> Текст1 </div>
   <div class="order-string-list"> Текст2 </div>
   <div class="order-string-list"> Текст3 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent .order-string-list{
    /* стили для неактивных .order-string-list */
}
.parent.active .order-string-list {
    /* стили для активных .order-string-list */
}
```

**Скрипт**

```
$("body").on("click", ".open-new", function(e) {
    $(".parent").toggleClass("active");   
});
```

Преимущество в том, что `.parent` хранит состояние, а не каждый отдельный `ordero-string-list`, что облегчает контроль.

**Хранить состояние нужно в статическом элементе, который не изменяется, а вот динамические пусть зависят от него.**